# Glassfish running sometimes slow?

Tags: java, glassfish, profiling

I know this sounds like a generic question, but I need some guidance.

We have a distributed system with `Java` swing client, `Glassfish 3.0.1` as application server and `PostgreSQL` as database. We are using `hessian` protocol for communication with the `Glassfish 3.0.1` server.

There are around `5` users using the client simultaneously. Everything is running fine, until all users say that their client stops responding for `10` seconds and then it continues to run fine for `15` minutes for example. And then the same thing happens. When I restart the server they say it is fine, but after half a day, again the same thing happens. I looked at the database logs, and I don't see queries above `1` second. I think the problem is connected with the communication to the `Glassfish` server(all clients cannot communicate to the server at the same time).

How could I approach the problem?

P.S When `glassfish` stops responding, I can't even open the `index.html` page properly.

Greetings,
Petar

Comment: Sounds like the JVM on which Glassfish is running is doing garbage collection, but without more details it's hard to say for sure. Use tools such as VisualVM (included with JDK 6 and newer) to monitor what's happening in the JVM.

Comment: Thank you, I am trying now `VisualVM` monitoring with the `Glassfish` plugin.

Comment: @Jesper - The maximum heap size of the `Glassfish` is `512 MB`. I think it is too small, what do you think? And it needs to garbage collect too often. I will try to increase it, but it won't be soon, it is a live environment:P

Comment: It's impossible to say whether that's too small or not, not knowing anything about your application. Glassfish itself doesn't need a lot of memory.

Comment: There are some performance bugs that were fixed in 3.12 I suggest reviewing the patch and considering an upgrade.

Comment: I too have the same issue.